# How can I move something from one database to another using Haskell?

Tags: mongodb, haskell, elasticsearch, io, functional-programming

I'm fairly new to Haskell; I've read countless tutorials and other resources on it, but whenever I decide to try to write programs doing anything remotely useful, I usually don't even know where to begin. I was recently listening to a podcast where Gabriel Gonzalez talked about how the best way to stay motivated is to actually use it for projects and just get writing, so I really want to use it for a task I have at hand.

So, I have a Mongo database which is constantly getting updated with items being scraped regularly, and an Elasticsearch database. The former will frequently get updated with items I have already scraped before, while the latter is populated with unique items. To achieve this I have a script (1000 lines of Node.js) which is constantly running and consuming the items in the Mongo database one by one, doing some checks to see if it's already in the Elasticsearch database, and adding it if it's not; afterwards, it's deleted from Mongo. This script is however a total mess.

I've been wanting to do this in Haskell, since Haskell is great for managing IO in a controlled manner from what I've read and heard, and since I like the idea of keeping pure functions for transforming the data and the parts of the program actually performing IO separate. I also assume a working Haskell solution would be more concise, and easier to reason about when changing things later.

So far I've managed to use the mongoDB package to do CRUD operations in Mongo by following the tutorial, but there are still a lot of things I don't understand about how it works. I find it harder to work with the bloodhound package for doing the same things in Elasticsearch, and I'm completely stumped as to how I would piece things together, especially while ensuring that the relevant items only get deleted from Mongo after having been successfully added to Elasticsearch.

I know this is a very broad question, but if anyone knows anything about this, or simply are able to give me some direction, I would appreciate it. In fact, all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in an useful way through the Stack Overflow format. You will likely get better results here by distilling what you are having trouble to achieve at this moment into a small, self-contained piece of code, and then asking a question about it.

Answer (score 5):

> I like the idea of keeping pure functions for transforming the data
>   and the parts of the program actually performing IO separate.

If you are starting with Haskell I would advise you to leave this in the back burner and just build a solution that works even if it has `IO` everywhere. As you gain confidence, you'll learn to see ways to restructure the code.

> I'm completely stumped as to how I would piece things together,
>   especially while ensuring that the relevant items only get deleted
>   from Mongo after having been successfully added to Elasticsearch.

Unless I'm missing somehting, that seems like pretty straightforward program logic!

If you have the following (completely invented, grossly simplified) functions

```
getDocumentFromMongo :: MongoGonnection -> IO Document

deleteFromMongo :: MongoConnection -> Document -> IO ()

isPresentInElastic :: ElasticConnection -> Document -> IO Bool

insertInElastic :: ElasticConnection -> Document -> IO ()
```

You could write an infinite loop like:

```
loader :: MongoConnection -> ElasticConnection -> IO r -- runs forever
loader mongoConn elasticConn = forever (do
    document <- getDocumentFromMongo mongoConn
    existsInElastic <- isPresentInElastic elasticConn document
    if existsInElastic
       then return ()
       else insertInElastic elasticConn document
    deleteFromMongo mongoConn document)
```

Of course, there are more things to consider. What to do if an [exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:3) is thrown while inserting in Elastic Search? You'll presumably need to use functions like `try`,[`bracket`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket),[`finally`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:finally) and [`onException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:onException) from [`Control.Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html).

Also, perhaps some level of concurrency is desired. There are [many](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html) [good](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm) [libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) for that, too.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. As you point out in the end, what to do when updating the Elasticsearch update fails is one of the things I need to figure out. I come from Python, and the way you describe it the exception handling sounds similar to how it's done in Python, which I didn't think was the case in Haskell.

Also, when running it forever in the manner you describe, how does it handle waiting when the Mongo database is empty and there is nothing to consume?

Comment: @Nicholas Tidemann Haskell has two flavor for signalling errors: exceptions and sum types like `Either` or `Maybe`. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/error-handling.html As for waiting, you can implement a simple polling mechanism using `threadDelay :: Int -> IO ()` from `Control.Concurrent`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay

Comment: Right, I'm at least familiar with both `Either` and `Maybe` by having read a lot about them, and I'll see if I can work it out. As for waiting, I also arrived at `threadDelay` being the preferred way, working similarly to `time.sleep` in Python, but since it's concurrent I guess it works a bit differently. I'll see if I can maky any progress, thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems you have demonstrated my comment to this question was wrong. This is a nice, perceptive answer.